# Why does foldr give me this error?

Tags: haskell

```
foldr (\x ante->[x]:[ante]) [4] [1,2,3]
```

So if I get foldr right, the first time the function `(\x ante->[x]:[ante])`  will do something, I will call this function f, it will be in:

```
   f 3 [4] = [3]:[[4]] = [[3],[4]]
```

Why doesn't the function do this? It shows this error instead:

```
* Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
  Expected type: [a]
    Actual type: [[a]]
* In the expression: [x] : [ante]
  In the first argument of `foldr', namely
    `(\ x ante -> [x] : [ante])'
  In the expression: foldr (\ x ante -> [x] : [ante]) [4] [1, 2, 3]
* Relevant bindings include
    ante :: [a] (bound at testefoldr.hs:51:21)
    x :: a (bound at testefoldr.hs:51:19)
    folder4 :: [a] (bound at testefoldr.hs:51:1)
   |51 | folder4 = foldr (\x ante->[x]:[ante]) [4] [1,2,3]
```

I created a `.hs` then I put

```
folder4 = foldr (\x ante->[x]:[ante]) [4] [1,2,3]
```

for faster testing. That's why there is folder4 in the error.

Comment: `foldr (\x ante->[x]:ante) [[4]] [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 4):

The `foldr` function has type:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

So that means that it takes as input an element (type `a`) of the list to fold, together with the accumulator (type `b`), and returns an accumulator (again type `b`). In case Haskell was not statically typed, it would each time wrap the accumulator in a new list. So it would result in:

```
[4]
-> [[3],[4]]
-> [[2],[[3],[4]]]
-> [[1],[[2],[[3],[4]]]]
```

which makes no sense.

There are two problems here:

1. if `ante` has type `b`, then `[x] : [ante]` has type `[b]`; and
2. the type of the initial accumulator `[4]` is not the result of the foldr.

So you can fix this by writing:

```
foldr (\x ante->[x]:ante) [[4]] [1,2,3]
```

Comment: small nitpick: if `ante` has type `b` wouldn't `[ante]` have type `[b]`?

Answer (score 3):

Let's pretend this type checks, and run it anyway

```
foldr (\x ante->[x]:[ante]) [4] [1,2,3]
```

Let's write `f` for `\x ante -> [x]:[ante]`.

```
foldr f [4] [1,2,3]
=
f 1 (f 2 (f 3 [4]))
=
f 1 (f 2 ([3]:[[4]]))
=
f 1 (f 2 [[3],[4]])
```

So far, so good.

```
=
f 1 ([2] : [[[3],[4]]])
=
f 1 [[2] , [[3],[4]] ]
```

Now we're in trouble. Is that a `[[Int]]` or a `[[[Int]]]`?
Things get even worse if we continue.

The problem is that `f` must return a value of the same type as that of its second argument. Otherwise, we can't compose `f` in the way `foldr` does. Your `f` does not do that, instead adding a `[]` to the type at every call.